# Optimize (Concatenate and Minify) RequireJS Projects

Tags: requirejs, amd, r.js

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me that RequireJS Projects can be minified only with r.js ? If there are other tools then how would these tools handle dependencies like this:
    require(['views/app'], function(AppView) {
      new AppView;
    });

Answer (score 0):

RequireJS performs two broad tasks: packaging a series of modules and minifying them.

1. "Packaging" here means laying out the modules for deployment. This may mean creating one bundles containing all the modules, two bundles containing two different sets of modules, an arbitrary number of bundles, or keeping all the modules as individual files.

   The packaging task often requires knowledge of the dependencies between modules and of how RequireJS works. It would be possible to use something else than `r.js` to do this task but at the end of the day a tool that understands the dependencies will end up replicating `r.js`' algorithms. So you might as well just use `r.js`.
2. Internally, `r.js` uses third-party libraries to perform the minification work. So it would be possible to use `r.js` to package the modules and *then* run a minifier to minify the resulting files. Once upon a time I've done that to hunt for an elusive bug. My recollection may be fuzzy but the important settings I remember are:

   - `optimize: "none"`
   - `skipDirOptimize: true`
   - `normalizeDirDefines: "all"`